# How to draw a line on a web page using vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to draw somethings (line, circle, etc.) on image box direcly.

I can not use this method.

```
<asp:Image ..... runat="server" src="drawing.aspx" ..... />
```

and "drawing.aspx"

```
Imports System.Drawing
Public Class Cizici
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
.
.
.
        Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg"
        Cizim_Alani.Save(Response.OutputStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: It's possible to do this method but it might be easier to use svg or doing it in javascript with a canvas.

Comment: Good old <hr> has died with HTML5. But still may be displayed as a horizontal rule.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "a line" are you looking for a horizontal line?

You can use this to draw a horizontal line from code behind:

In html add this wherever you want it to appear:

```
<span><asp:Literal ID="HRContentLiteral" runat="server"></asp:Literal></span>
```

Then in the code behind add the following code to define what you want to appear.  This one displays a horizontal line.

```
HRContentLiteral.Text = "<hr></hr>"
```

But if you want diagonal line you could use:

```
HRContentLiteral.Text = "<svg height='210' width='500'><line x1='0' y1='0' x2='200' y2='200' style='stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2' /></svg>"
```

And if you want a circle you could use:

```
HRContentLiteral.Text = "<svg height='100' width='100'><circle cx='50' cy='50' r='40' stroke='black' stroke-width='3' fill='red' /></svg>"
```

You can find other shape examples at: https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_intro.asp and you don't have to use them within a literal, that just gives you the ability to set them from the code behind since I have set the literal to run on the server.

I hope this helps.